# Forcing end of quarter date for as.Date(as.yearqtr())

Tags: r, zoo

as.yearqtr() from the `zoo` package appears to use the beginning of the quarter:

```
library(zoo)
x <- "2015-05-17"
x <- as.Date(x)
x <- as.Date(as.yearqtr(x))
x

# [1] "2015-04-01"
```

How might I instead grab the end of quarter?

```
x

# [1] "2015-06-30"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `frac = 1` as shown:

```
x <- as.Date("2015-05-17")
as.Date( as.yearqtr(x), frac = 1 )
```

giving:

```
[1] "2015-06-30"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(zoo)

x <- as.Date("2015-05-17")
x <- as.Date(as.yearqtr(x)+0.25)-1

x
# [1] "2015-06-30"
```

`as.yearqtr(x)+0.25` gives you the next quarter. `as.Date`gives you the first day in this next quarter. `-1` delivers the last day of the original quarter.