# Pandas datetime function to get the date at the end of the quarter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe that contains a year-quarter column `df.period`
and I want to convert that column into the `DatetimeIndex` with this code.

```
# path is my filepath
df = pd.read_excel(path, skiprows =[1,2,3,4]) # unread first four rows
idx = pd.to_datetime(df.period)
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(idx))
```

The code works well for me; however, it returns the first date of each quarter on `PeriodIdx`.

```
+------------+--------+
| PeriodIdx  | Period |
+------------+--------+
| 2000-01-01 | 2000Q1 |
| 2000-04-01 | 2000Q2 |
| ...        | ...    |
+------------+--------+
```

But my purposed output is to get the end date of each quarter as shown below.

```
+------------+--------+
| PeriodIdx  | Period |
+------------+--------+
| 2000-03-31 | 2000Q1 |
| 2000-06-30 | 2000Q2 |
| ...        | ...    |
+------------+--------+
```

Refer to the solution in R [Forcing end of quarter date for as.Date(as.yearqtr())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391271/forcing-end-of-quarter-date-for-as-dateas-yearqtr) , is there any Pandas function for the last date of the quarter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to add offset:

```
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(df.period) + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(3),
                       name='PeriodIdx')

df.set_index(idx)
```

Output:

```
            Period
PeriodIdx         
2000-03-31  2000Q1
2000-06-30  2000Q2
```

Comment: It returns the last date of each month, not last date in each quarter. (`2000Q2` should returns `2000-06-30` not `2000-04-30`)

Comment: @sikawit Thanks for pointing that out. It's easy to fix with `MonthEnd(3)`. See update.